# How can I filter dojo grid using my HTML dropdown with grid’s column “SchedulingAssistant”

Tags: dojo

I have an HTML dropdown with values “aa, bb, cc”. How can I filter dojo grid using my HTML dropdown with grid’s column “SchedulingAssistant”. 
I am using the following code to create and display grid:

```
    var CurrentColumnsLayout;       
var CurrentData = {identifier: 'id',label: 'id',items: []};
var ConvertedDisplayArray = $.toJSON(DisplayArray); 
var EvalDisplayArray = eval('(' +ConvertedDisplayArray+ ')');

for(var j = 0, l = EvalDisplayArray.length; j < EvalDisplayArray.length; j++)
{
    CurrentData.items.push(dojo.mixin({id:j}, EvalDisplayArray[j%l]));
}

CurrentDataStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data:CurrentData});    
CurrentColumnsLayout = [{field: 'id',name: 'id',width: 'auto',hidden:'true'},{field: 'CaseID',name: 'Case ID',width: 'auto'},{field: 'SchedulingAssistant',name: 'Schd. Assistant',width: 'auto'},{field: 'ServiceStatus',name: 'Status',width: 'auto', formatter:FormatStatus}];   
var CurrentGrid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({store: CurrentDataStore,structure: CurrentColumnsLayout,noDataMessage: "No results found.", selectionMode: 'single'},document.createElement('div'));
dojo.byId("IntakeFirstDiv").appendChild(CurrentGrid.domNode);   
CurrentGrid.startup();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the filter() method on the grid : http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/grid/DataGrid#filtering-data

So in your dropdown, you would add something like this to your onChange event :

```
grid.filter({yourColumn: 'someValue'});
```